# Thymeleaf equivalent of c:url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get a thymeleaf button to go to an mvc controller when clicked similar to how the c url work

```
<td><a  class="btn btn-success" href="<c:url value="/displayWikis" />">&nbsp;&nbspShow Wiki List&nbsp;&nbsp</a></td>
```

currently my code is as follows in my thymeleaf page

```
<td><button type="button"  th:href="@{/getAll}">Get All Post </button></td>
```

This is the thymelead page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">


<title>MVC Home</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}"
rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

link href="../static/css/bootstrap-theme.css"
th:href="@{css/bootstrap-theme.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-2.2.2.js"
th:src="@{js/jquery-2.2.2.js}"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/tether.js"
th:src="@{js/tether.js}"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.js"
th:src="@{js/bootstrap.js}"></script>


</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">

        <h1>Form</h1>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/mvchome}" th:object="${post}"
            method="post">

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{userAcctName}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{city}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="save">Submit post</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button"  th:href="@{/getAll}">Get All Post </button></td>

                </tr>


            </table>


        </form>



    </div>
    <div>
    <!--        <button type="button" th:href="@{/getAll}"> Get All </button> -->
    </div>

    <!--  Results Block -->

    <th:block th:each="post : ${postsList}">


        <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title" id="test" th:text="${post.subject}">Subject</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted" th:text="${post.created}">Date
                    Created</h6>
            </div>

            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text" th:text="${post.content}">Post Data</p>
                <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                    data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title"
                    data-content="th:text='${post.city}'">See Popover</button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted" th:text="${post.temperature}"></div>
        </div>

    </th:block>



</div>

<script>
    function getAllByUser() {

        $.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : "https://localhost:8443/api/getAllForUser",
            cache : false,
            data : 'user=' + $("#userAcctName").val(),
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response);

                //some how pass this response data to ${postsList}

                $('#test').html("" + response[0].subject);

                $(".card").children().removeClass('hidden');
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
            },
            error : function() {
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        //          $(".bg-success").children().addClass('hidden');

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the controller code

```
@Controller
public class PostController {

private final PostService postService;

@Inject
public PostController(final PostService postService){
    this.postService=postService;
}



@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
    return "home";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/mvchome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mvchome(Model model) {
    Post post = new Post();

    model.addAttribute("post", post);
    return "mvchome";
}



@RequestMapping(value = "/mvchome", method=RequestMethod.POST)
//public String create(@Valid Post post, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
public ModelAndView create(@Valid Post post) {
//      if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
//          return "mvchome";
//      }
    //Post post = new Post(0, 1, 0, content,content, new Date(),userAcctName,city, null, null, null);
    post.setParentId(0);
    post.setDisplayOrder(1);
    post.setIndentLevel(0);
    post.setSubject(post.getContent());
    post.setCreated(new Date());
    post.setLatitude(null);
    post.setLongtitude(null);
    post.setTemperature(null);
    postService.savePost(post);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mvchome");

    mav.addObject("postsList", post);
    Post newpost = new Post();

    mav.addObject("post", newpost);
    return mav;

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/getAll")
//public String create(@Valid Post post, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
public ModelAndView getAll() {
//      if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
//          return "mvchome";
//      }

    List<Post> postList=postService.findAllPosts();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mvchome");
    mav.addObject("postsList", postList);
    return mav;

}

}
```

I've searched around and so far I can't find a similar functionality.
Can any one point me in the right direction?

Thanks

****Followed as suggested however now I'm getting this error

```
    23:50:25.592 [http-nio-8443-exec-10] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8443-exec-10] Exception processing template "mvchome": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (mvchome:44)
23:50:25.593 [http-nio-8443-exec-10] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (mvchome:44)] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'post' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Your code is answer of your question :)   `<td><a  class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{/displayWikis}">Show Wiki List</a></td>`

Comment: I tried that previously, however I'm getting an error

Comment: Well, it tells you what you need to add `BindingResult`. So change your controller method to `public ModelAndView create(@Valid Post post, BindingResult result)`

Comment: I was able to figure it out but definitely thanks a lot for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my error of "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name" the issue was that the my form was expecting a post object, however in the getAll method I was not providing a new post object. To resolve the error here's what I did

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAll")
// public String create(@Valid Post post, BindingResult bindingResult, Model
// model) {
public ModelAndView getAll() {
    // if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    // return "mvchome";
    // }

    List<Post> postList = postService.findAllPosts();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mvchome");
    mav.addObject("postsList", postList);
    Post newpost = new Post();

    mav.addObject("post", newpost);
    return mav;

}
```